Must the neighborhood of a point on the edge of a metric space be open
I just started reading Baby Rudin and found its definition (2.18) on neighborhood:

Let $X$ be a metric space. A neighborhood of $p \in X$ is a set $N_r(p) \subseteq X$ consisting of all $q \in X$ such that $d(p, q)<r$, for some $r>0$.

And it went on proving that (2.19) every neighborhood is an open set.

For the question stated in the title, my thought process is:
Consider a subset $X=[0, 2] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $X$ should be a metric space since it is the subset of another metric space. Consider the point $p=0 \in X$ and its neighborhood $N_1(0)=[0, 1)$. It seems like this neighborhood is not an open set.
From here on I'm a bit confused. Is $0$ an interior point of $E=N_1(0)$ or a limit point of $E$ or perhaps both? As by definition,

A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E \subseteq X$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q\neq p$ such that $q \in E$.
A point $p$ is an interior point of $E$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N \subset E$.
$E$ is open if every point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$.
$E$ is closed if every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$.

So perhaps, if $0$ is both an interior point and a limit point of $E$, then $E$ is still open (not closed since the limit point $1$ is not in $E$).
However my intuition tells me that I shouldn't call $[0, 1)$ an open set that confidently... at least I should call it something like a half-open set.

So did I misuse any definition, or is $[0, 1)$ simply called open under my definition of $X$?

Yes, $0$ is an interior point of $[0,1)$ in $X$ and, yes, $[0,1)$ is an open subset of $X$.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks a lot! I should've just let my intuition slip away...

It is, in fact, The open ball of radius $\frac 2 3$ around $\frac 1  3$.

This is not a good definition of neighbourhood. Neighbourhood doesn't always even mean "open". It just means, "contains an open neighbourhood of $p$". I mention this so you don't get confused when you see other people using the term in its standard, different way

$[0, 1)$ is open set in $[0, 2]$ but not open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

@MadhanKumar What is $n$?

typo sorry.....

One thing I will remark is that for metric spaces, there really isn't a notion of "edges" to the best of my knowledge. The closest I can think of has to do with completions of incomplete (so non-compact) metric spaces, but it doesn't quite match, as I wouldn't think of (for example) $\sqrt 2$ as being somehow on an "edge" of the rational interval $[0,2]\cap\Bbb Q,$ even though it's an element of the completion that doesn't lie in the original space.
